# Javascript Django | Hidden oculpa input bien, pero mantiene la zona del input y el label a la vista

Tags: javascript, django

Por algún error, CSS hidden oculta el input, pero conserva el espacio que lo ocupa y deja el title del label a la vista.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Javascript**:

```
<script>
    autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatusNoOkDetail_preventive();
    function autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatusNoOkDetail_preventive(){
        var elem = document.getElementById("autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatus_preventive");
        var x = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].text;
        //alert(x);
        if(x=="No OK"){
            document.getElementById("autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatusNoOkDetail_preventive").style.visibility = "visible";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatusNoOkDetail_preventive").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
        
    }
</script>
```

**Forms.py**

```
self.fields['autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatus_preventive'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control','id':'autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatus_preventive','onchange':"autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatusNoOkDetail_preventive()"})
```

**HTML que ejecuta función javascript que debe ocultar "textarea" y "label":**

```
<label for="autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatus_preventive">Estado de LEDs de alarma:</label> <select name="autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatus_preventive" class="form-control" id="autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatus_preventive" onchange="autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatusNoOkDetail_preventive()">
  <option value="1" selected>OK</option>
  <option value="2">No OK</option>
  <option value="3">NP</option>
```

**HTML a ocultar según select. Oculta "textarea" pero no oculta "label":**

```
<label for="autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatusNoOkDetail_preventive">Observaciones o fallo en estado alarmas de Led:</label> <textarea name="autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatusNoOkDetail_preventive" cols="40" rows="10" maxlength="40" class="form-control" id="autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatusNoOkDetail_preventive" style="visibility:hidden">
</textarea>
```

Comment: Podrías indicarnos el código ?

Comment: Tienes razón, disculpa. Ya lo he añadido. ; )

Comment: Podrías probar aplicando `display:none` al elemento que quieres ocultar en lugar de visibility:hidden

Comment: *Por algún error* ?? No es ningún error, `visibility: hidden;` mantiene reservado el espacio, mientras que `display: none;` hace que el espacio sea ignorado.

Comment: Cierto, así es. Muchas gracias. ; )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que funcione de la manera esperada hay que utilizar `diplay` en vez de `visibility` ya que éste último reserva el lugar del elemento.

```
document.getElementById("autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatusNoOkDetail_preventive").style.display= "none";
```

para que el efecto de ocultado funcione también para el label es necesario agregar la siguiente línea.

```
document.querySelector("label[for='autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatusNoOkDetail_preventive']").style.display = "none";
```

El código completo y funcional es como sigue:

```js
    autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatusNoOkDetail_preventive();
    function autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatusNoOkDetail_preventive(){
        var elem = document.getElementById("autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatus_preventive");
        var x = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].text;
        //alert(x);
        if(x=="No OK"){
            document.getElementById("autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatusNoOkDetail_preventive").style.display = "block";
            document.querySelector("label[for='autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatusNoOkDetail_preventive']").style.display = "block";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatusNoOkDetail_preventive").style.display = "none";
            document.querySelector("label[for='autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatusNoOkDetail_preventive']").style.display = "none";
        }
        
    }
```

```html
<p>
    <label for="autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatus_preventive">Estado de LEDs de alarma:</label>
    <br />
    <select name="autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatus_preventive" 
            class="form-control" 
            id="autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatus_preventive" 
            onchange="autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatusNoOkDetail_preventive()">
        <option value="1" selected>OK</option>
        <option value="2">No OK</option>
        <option value="3">NP</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <label for="autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatusNoOkDetail_preventive">
      Observaciones o fallo en estado alarmas de Led:
    </label>
    <br />
    <textarea name="autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatusNoOkDetail_preventive"
              cols="40" rows="10" maxlength="40" class="form-control" 
              id="autVisualInspectionOfAlarmLedStatusNoOkDetail_preventive"> 
    </textarea>
    <br />
    <button>Otro elemento</button>
</p>
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto! Muchas gracias Blasito.